# Ошибка в Excel при запуске макроса Run-time error '75'

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Как исправить такую ошибку. Поможет ли переустановка Visual Basic или Excel?
[image: Каким способом можно обойти такую ошибку?]

Comment: Не получается достучаться до файла... Может, показать пример, где эта ошибка возникает?

Comment: Нажмите кнопку Debug. Посмотрите, какой оператор привёл к ошибке. Смотрите, к чему он там обращается, и почему на это что-то нет прав доступа. *Поможет ли переустановка Visual Basic или Excel?* Крайне вряд ли.